# Built-in Postgres' Automatic Backup

Tags: postgresql, backup

Is there any automatic built-in mechanism in postgres to backup data if the data have exceeded the maximum permissible storage amount?

Comment: "No". But a shell script such as this one should not be too difficult to write. What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet, I just want to make sure. I was meaning to use worker before, but if built-in mechanism were included, I would use that. Thanks for the answer tho @KookieMonster

Answer (score 0):

The only maximum permissible storage amount is the amount of storage your disk has. When you're running out of space, postgreSQL will simply stop. (with a PANIC message)

You have to monitor your disks free space to prevent it to happen...

Sadly documentation is quite light on it:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/diskusage.html

Comment: I think I'll be using background process to periodically archive data